# Total height of SCNNode childNodes

Tags: ios, swift, refactoring, scenekit

I'm currently using the following to get the total height of all of the child nodes in a `SCNNode`. Is there a more efficient/better/shorter/more swift-like way to do this?

```
CGFloat(columnNode.childNodes.reduce(CGFloat()) {
    let geometry = $1.geometry! as SCNBox
    return $0 + geometry.height
})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, and a way that'll get you a more correct answer, too. Summing the height of all the child nodes' geometries...

- only works if the geometry is an `SCNBox`
- doesn't account for the child nodes' transforms (what if they're moved, rotated or scaled?)
- doesn't account for the parent node's transform (what if you want height in scene space?)

What you want is the [`SCNBoundingVolume`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnboundingvolume) protocol, which applies to all nodes and geometries, and describes the smallest rectangular or spherical space containing all of a node's (and its subnodes') content.

In Swift 3, this is super easy:

```
let (min, max) = columnNode.boundingBox
```

After this, `min` and `max` are the coordinates of the lower-rear-left and upper-front-right corners of the smallest possible box containing everything inside `columnNode`, no matter how that content is arranged (and what kind of geometry is involved). These coordinates are expressed in the same system as `columnNode.position`, so if the "height" you're looking for is in the y-axis direction of that space, just subtract the y-coordinates of those two vectors:

```
let height = max.y - min.y
```

---

In Swift 2, the syntax for it is a little weird, but it works well enough:

```
var min = SCNVector3Zero
var max = SCNVector3Zero
columnNode.getBoundingBoxMin(&min, max: &max)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't appear to account for scale? For instance, if you do `columNode.scale = SCNVector3(x: 2, y: 2, z: 2)` before computing the height, the height remains the same instead of being scaled. Or are we doing something wrong?

Comment: Bounding volumes are expressed in the node's own coordinate system. If you want a bounding volume relative to something else (like the parent node) you'll have to [convert](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnnode/1408018-convertposition) those min and max points.